# Change content after data has been entered into the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I have a page where the user enters his email address to subscribe to a newsletter. This is then forwarded to a PHP file via an action tag in the form, which then saves it in a database. The page will then be updated.

Now I would like to give the user some feedback that everything went well.

Above the button there is a text with an id = notify- It says something like: Subscribe to our newsletter. Now I want this text to be replaced with something new, but with the same CSS formatting. How do I do that ?

Comment: print it in the php file if the save was successful

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

But as lack of knowledge on how actually you have build your "subscribe to newsletter" feature it's kinda hard to answer exact.

As you said you are forwarding the mailId to a PHP file via form submission then you can do something like this.

**Method 1:-**

subscribe.php (the page where you subscribe to newsletter)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['success']))
{
if($_POST['success']== 1)
echo '<script>document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "Subscribed successfully..!";</script>';
else 
echo '<script>document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "Something went wrong..!";</script>';
}
?>

//form for subscription
<form action="action.php">
<input type = "email" name="email">
<input type = "submit" value = "Subscribe" >
</form>
<div id="notify"></div>
//after submission it will go to php file and then the database thing will be done as you said
```

action.php

```
<form name="success" action="subscribe.html">
<input type="hidden" name="success" value="" id= "successcode">
</form>
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

//do whatever you want 
//database thing or whatever

if(//success)
{
echo '<script> document.getElementById("successcode").value=1;
document.forms["success"].submit();</script>';
}
else
echo '<script> document.getElementById("successcode").value=0;
document.forms["success"].submit();</script>';
?>
```

**Method 2:-** (requires single file )

```
<?php
if(isset($POST['email']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];//get the mail
//do the stuff here...
if (//success)
echo '<script>document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "Subscribed successfully..!";</script>';
else
echo '<script>document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "Something went wrong..!";</script>';
    ?>
    
    //form for subscription
    <form action=" ">
    <input type = "email" name = "email">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Subscribe" >
    </form>
    <div id="notify"></div>
    //after submission it will be submitted to same file and then the database thing will be done as you said
```

There might be some errors with javascript that you can easily sort out.

There are lot lot more way you can alert user on success of subscription, like cookies, JS alerts, ajax calls etc

Answer (score 0):

You could query the element using JavaScript and update its content like this:

```js
document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "Your new text";
```